# Check if one date is between two dates

Tags: javascript, date

I need to check if a `date` - a string in `dd/mm/yyyy` format -
falls between two other dates having the same format `dd/mm/yyyy`

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
var dateFrom = "02/05/2013";
var dateTo = "02/09/2013";
var dateCheck = "02/07/2013";

var from = Date.parse(dateFrom);
var to   = Date.parse(dateTo);
var check = Date.parse(dateCheck );

if((check <= to && check >= from))      
    alert("date contained");
```

I used debugger and checked, the `to` and `from` variables have `isNaN` value.
Could you help me?

Comment: Daniel, you need to update the corrrect answer. The answer with more votes doesn't check for dates only for months

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`Date.parse` supports the format  `mm/dd/yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy`. For the latter, either use a library like moment.js or do something as shown below

```
var dateFrom = "02/05/2013";
var dateTo = "02/09/2013";
var dateCheck = "02/07/2013";

var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
var d2 = dateTo.split("/");
var c = dateCheck.split("/");

var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
var to   = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
var check = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1])-1, c[0]);

console.log(check > from && check < to)
```

Comment: +1 for correctly parsing the date string and not leaving it up to an implementation dependent parser.

Comment: Consider db conventions, first date should be inclusive. e.g. `check >= from && check < to`

Comment: @Diode
check :02/23/2018 from:11/20/2018 to:12/31/2018 it returns true.

Comment: @chudasamachirag: The question was about parsing dd/mm/yyyy format. These dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 81):

Instead of comparing the dates directly, compare the getTime() value of the date.  The getTime() function returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 as an integer-- should be trivial to determine if one integer falls between two other integers.

Something like

```
if((check.getTime() <= to.getTime() && check.getTime() >= from.getTime()))      alert("date contained");
```

Comment: `NaN` neither has a `GetTime` nor a `getTime` method?

Comment: It will perfectly be working when date format is like - 02/05/2013 but when date is in iso format(date+time) like - 2019-09-12T13:02:14.291Z then use the  [setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method before compare dates, Ex -  
`let compareDate = new Date('checkDate').setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 let startDate = new Date('startDate').setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 let endDate = new Date('endDate').setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
 console.log(compareDate <= endDate && compareDate >= startDate);`

Hope it will help others :)

Comment: @SayanSamanta: Your solution is simple & it works. Thanks. Note for others: Time is not checked here.

Answer (score 25):

Try what's below. It will help you...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/146/

**Script :**

```
if(dateCheck("02/05/2013","02/09/2013","02/07/2013"))
    alert("Availed");
else
    alert("Not Availed");

function dateCheck(from,to,check) {

    var fDate,lDate,cDate;
    fDate = Date.parse(from);
    lDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(check);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Bergi: If the Date is `NAN` then this function `return False` So the `Date you check Or Pass` is `Not Availed` or `In Valid` and this is the HELL difference between the code of mine and him

Comment: But the OP's if-condition does that as well? And the question was about the date *being* `NaN` in the first place (which it is not in all browsers)

Comment: What if I wanted to check if `now` falls under `7:00am` to `9:00pm`

Comment: dateCheck("20/01/2015","22/01/2015","21/02/2015") this case doesnt work

Comment: @BhavinRana This case does not work because you use dd/mm/yyyy - correct would be mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 11):

The answer that has 50 votes doesn't check for date in only checks for months. That answer is not correct. The code below works.

```
var dateFrom = "01/08/2017";
var dateTo = "01/10/2017";
var dateCheck = "05/09/2017";

var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
var d2 = dateTo.split("/");
var c = dateCheck.split("/");

var from = new Date(d1);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
var to   = new Date(d2);
var check = new Date(c);

alert(check > from && check < to);
```

This is the code posted in another answer and I have changed the dates and that's how I noticed it doesn't work

```
var dateFrom = "02/05/2013";
var dateTo = "02/09/2013";
var dateCheck = "07/07/2013";

var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
var d2 = dateTo.split("/");
var c = dateCheck.split("/");

var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
var to   = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
var check = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1])-1, c[0]);


alert(check > from && check < to);
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplified way of doing this based on the accepted answer.

In my case I needed to check if current date (Today) is pithing the range of two other dates so used newDate() instead of hardcoded values but you can get the point how you can use hardcoded dates.

```
var currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
var from = new Date('2020/01/01');
var to   = new Date('2020/01/31');
var check = new Date(currentDate);

console.log(check > from && check < to);
```

Comment: this code does not work in safari

Comment: @Ulugbek just tested in latest Safari 15.6 and it's working. Here's a test link - https://codepen.io/andrew_mykhalchuk/pen/gOejKpW

Answer (score 3):

I have created customize function to validate given date is between two dates or not.

```
var getvalidDate = function(d){ return new Date(d) }

function validateDateBetweenTwoDates(fromDate,toDate,givenDate){
    return getvalidDate(givenDate) <= getvalidDate(toDate) && getvalidDate(givenDate) >= getvalidDate(fromDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Date Prototype method written in typescript:

```
Date.prototype.isBetween = isBetween;
interface Date { isBetween: typeof isBetween }
function isBetween(minDate: Date, maxDate: Date): boolean {
  if (!this.getTime) throw new Error('isBetween() was called on a non Date object');
  return !minDate ? true : this.getTime() >= minDate.getTime()
    && !maxDate ? true : this.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing that @Diode, the first answer, but i made the condition with a range of dates, i hope this example going to be useful for someone

e.g (the same code to example with array of dates)

```js
var dateFrom = "02/06/2013";
var dateTo = "02/09/2013";

var d1 = dateFrom.split("/");
var d2 = dateTo.split("/");

var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
var to   = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]); 



var dates= ["02/06/2013", "02/07/2013", "02/08/2013", "02/09/2013", "02/07/2013", "02/10/2013", "02/011/2013"];

dates.forEach(element => {
   let parts = element.split("/");
   let date= new Date(parts[2], parseInt(parts[1]) - 1, parts[0]);
        if (date >= from && date < to) {
           console.log('dates in range', date);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for example your date is coming like this & you need to install momentjs for advance date features.

```
let cmpDate = Thu Aug 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

    let format = "MM/DD/YYYY";
    let startDate: any = moment().format(format);
    let endDate: any = moment().add(30, "days").format(format);
    let compareDate: any = moment(cmpDate).format(format);
    var startDate1 = startDate.split("/");
    var startDate2 = endDate.split("/");
    var compareDate1 = compareDate.split("/");

    var fromDate = new Date(startDate1[2], parseInt(startDate1[1]) - 1, startDate1[0]);
    var toDate = new Date(startDate2[2], parseInt(startDate2[1]) - 1, startDate2[0]);
    var checkDate = new Date(compareDate1[2], parseInt(compareDate1[1]) - 1, compareDate1[0]);

    if (checkDate > fromDate && checkDate < toDate) {
      ... condition works between current date to next 30 days
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="eventCheck"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// ----------------------------------------------------//
// Todays date
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

// Add Zero if it number is between 0-9
if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd;
}
if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm;
}

var today = yyyy + '' + mm + '' + dd ;


// ----------------------------------------------------//
// Day of event
var endDay = 15; // day 15
var endMonth = 01; // month 01 (January)
var endYear = 2017; // year 2017

// Add Zero if it number is between 0-9
if(endDay<10) {
    endDay = '0'+endDay;
} 
if(endMonth<10) {
    endMonth = '0'+endMonth;
}

// eventDay - date of the event
var eventDay = endYear + '/' + endMonth + '/' + endDay;
// ----------------------------------------------------//



// ----------------------------------------------------//
// check if eventDay has been or not
if ( eventDay < today ) {
    document.getElementById('eventCheck').innerHTML += 'Date has passed (event is over)';  // true
} else {
    document.getElementById('eventCheck').innerHTML += 'Date has not passed (upcoming event)'; // false
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zm75cq2a/

Answer (score 0):

This may feel a bit more intuitive. The parameter is just a valid date string.
This function returns true if the date passed as argument is in the current week, or false if not.

```
function isInThisWeek(dateToCheck){
// Create a brand new Date instance
const WEEK = new Date()

// create a date instance with the function parameter 
//(format should be like dd/mm/yyyy or any javascript valid date format )
const DATEREF = new Date(dateToCheck)

// If the parameter is a not a valid date, return false
if(DATEREF instanceof Date && isNaN(DATEREF)){ 
  console.log("invalid date format")
  return false}

// Get separated date infos (the date of today, the current month and the current year) based on the date given as parameter
const [dayR, monthR, yearR] = [DATEREF.getDate(), DATEREF.getMonth(), DATEREF.getFullYear()]

// get Monday date by substracting the day index (number) in the week from the day value (count) 
//in the month (like october 15th - 5 (-> saturday index)) and +1 because 
//JS weirdly starts the week on sundays
const monday = (WEEK.getDate() - WEEK.getDay()) + 1

// get Saturday date
const sunday = monday + 6

// Start verification
if (yearR !== WEEK.getFullYear())  { console.log("WRONG YEAR"); return false }
if (monthR !== WEEK.getMonth()) { console.log("WRONG MONTH"); return false }
if(dayR >= monday && dayR <= sunday) { return true }
else {console.log("WRONG DAY"); return false}

}
```

Comment: Hi @Wilfried.
could you please format your code to explain the solution you are providing. 
Currently the answer dooes not look working properly. 
Thank you!

Comment: I'll do so. @TobiasSchäfer
But what's not working properly ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all cases.

```
var curr = new Date("12/01/2023"); // get current date
console.log("curr.getDate()",curr.getDate());
console.log("curr.getDay()",curr.getDay());
var first = curr.getDate() - (curr.getDay()-1); //-1to make monday first day.
console.log(first)
var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)); // 
console.log("first date",firstday)
var firstDay_no=firstday.getDate();
console.log("firstDay_no",firstDay_no)
var last = firstDay_no+ 6; // last day is the first day no + 6
console.log("last",last)
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)); //

console.log("last date",lastday)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const dateFrom = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 1); 
const dateTo = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + 1, 0, 6);

const dateCheck = new Date("02/07/2013");

const isBetween = dateCheck >= dateFrom && dateCheck <= dateTo;

console.log('is date in range?', isBetween);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var gdate='01-05-2014';
        date =Date.parse(gdate.split('-')[1]+'-'+gdate.split('-')[0]+'-'+gdate.split('-')[2]);
        if(parseInt(date) < parseInt(Date.now()))
        {
            alert('small');
        }else{
            alert('big');
        }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CY7W/)

Answer (score -1):

This question is very generic, hence people who are using date libraries also check for the answer, but I couldn't find any answer for the date libraries, hence I am posting the answer for [Luxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/luxon) users.

```
const fromDate = '2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z';
const toDate = '2022-06-30T23:59:59.999Z';
const inputDate = '2022-08-09T20:26:13.380Z';

if (
  DateTime.fromISO(inputDate) >= DateTime.fromISO(fromDate) &&
  DateTime.fromISO(inputDate) <= DateTime.fromISO(toDate)
) {
  console.log('within range');
} else {
  console.log('not in range');
}
```