# how can I enable and disable a form in a codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

please I am developing an application which involves admin section and client section, I want to control registration period on client section. For instance, from one date e.g. 05/03/2017 to another date 05/04/2017, the form should be disabled.

Comment: do you want to display form in disable mode for that assigned time frame or form will not be display for this time frame?

Comment: try looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/16080378/3172875

Comment: @Bhaskar form will not display. Once the time set elapses, the form disappears from view until it is set again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check example this will automatically display form on your giving date

```
<?php
$today = date('d/m/y');
$date2 = "05/03/2017";
if(strtotime($today) == strtotime($date2))
{
    $display = "block";
}
else
{
    $display = "none";
}
?>
<style> 
form {
    display: <?php echo $display; ?>;
}
<style>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Codeigniter Query**

```
public function formEvent()
{
    $result = array();

    $today = date('d/m/y');    // get today date 

    /* get form submit values */

    #$startDate = $this->input->post('start_date')     // form input name should be start date 
    $endDate = $this->input->post('end_date');       //form input name should be end_date 

    /* check condition for enable or disable form */

    if(strtotime($today) == strtotime($endDate))
    {
        $display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        $display = "none";
    }

    $result['display'] = $display ;

    $this->load->view('pagename', $result);   // view containing form 
}
```

Comment: let me try it. But what I intend to do is to create a form handler where I can set the date parameters. The admin can choice date of his choice from date pickers and click on "implement", then form get enabled and disabled when the expire date elapses

Comment: check updated answer i have created a function for idea to understand you the way how we do such task in codeigniter controller ..