# How can I validate if a date occurs between two dates with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a date occurs between two dates. 
If this date occurs between these two dates the function should return true, otherwise it should return false.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    function dateCheck() {
        var fDate,lDate,cDate;
        fDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date()); // firstdate
        cDate = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', 
        jQuery('#challenge_date').val()); // date from form
        lDate =  jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());
        lDate.setDate(lDate.getDate() + 7); // lastdate

        if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
            alert("true");
            return true;
        }

        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return dateCheck()">
    <input type="date" name="challenge_date" id="challenge_date">
    <input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

Can anyone point out my mistake of give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: jquery has no date functions - you're thinking of javascript

Comment: The result of `formatDate()` is a string. You need to work with actual Date() objects.

Comment: please visit :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using html native date input type. Therefore no need is there to use jQuery datepicker API. Simply create date object from the input value and compare with other Date objects.

```js
function dateCheck() {
        var fDate,lDate,cDate;
        fDate = new Date(); // firstdate
        cDate = new Date($('#challenge_date').val()); // date from form
        lDate = new Date();
        lDate.setDate(lDate.getDate() + 7); // lastdate
        
        if(Date.parse(cDate) <= Date.parse(lDate) && Date.parse(cDate) >= Date.parse(fDate)){
            alert("true");
            return true;
        }

        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return dateCheck()">
    <input type="date" name="challenge_date" id="challenge_date">
    <input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Date function does not support dd/mm/yyyy. So try this

```
function dateCheck() {
        var fDate,lDate,cDate;
        fDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date()); // firstdate

        cDate = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', jQuery('#challenge_date').val()); // date from form

        lDate =  jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());

        var dateFrom = fDate.split("-");
        var dateTo = lDate.split("-");
        var dateCheck = cDate.split("-");

        var from = new Date(dateFrom[2], parseInt(dateFrom[1])-1, dateFrom[0]);  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
        var to   = new Date(dateTo[2], parseInt(dateTo[1])-1, dateTo[0]);
        var check = new Date(dateCheck[2], parseInt(dateCheck[1])-1, dateCheck[0]);

        if((check <= to && check >= from)) {
            alert("true");
            return true;
        }

        alert("false");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get your script working. When I check the console it says: lDate.getDate() is not a function

Comment: It doesn't work because fDate and lDate is the same now. I need lDate to be the date of today + 7 days. Thanks for your effort =)