# Jquery Filter array by date range

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array that contains date objects.

But the data is too large to parse everything. I want to filter results by date range (eg: between 10 days ago to the 10 days). So far, I can only filter with a single date.

Here's my code. I just don't how to go about achieving that.

```
var today = new Date();
var d = today.getDay();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

var eventParsed = JSON.parse(eventsObjects).filter(({
    date
}) => date === today);

console.log(eventParsed);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can avoid the string manipulation all together and just do some date comparisons like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var tenDaysAgo = new Date();
var tenDaysFromNow = new Date();
tenDaysAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 10);
tenDaysFromNow.setDate(today.getDate() + 10);

var eventParsed = JSON.parse(eventsObjects).filter(({
    date
}) => date >= tenDaysAgo && date <= tenDaysFromNow);

console.log(eventParsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the bound dates such as today minus 10 days and today plus 10 days and then, use them in the filter :

```
function formatDate(date)
{
    var d = date.getDay();
    var dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
}

function getDateFromTodayPlus(numberOfDays)
{
    const d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + numberOfDays);
    return formatDate(d);
}

const TenDaysAgoString = getDateFromTodayPlus(-10);

const TenDaysAfterString = getDateFromTodayPlus(10);

// And then, in your filter :

var eventParsed = JSON.parse(eventsObjects).filter(({
    date
}) => TenDaysAgoString <= date && date <= TenDaysAfterString);
```

Comment: Worked, though i went for a leaner solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the data sorted? Because then this is a very simple pick by using a binary search and picking out the contiguous range. If it's not sorted and sorting it is not viable then you can use JS date objects to determine if a date is inside your range when filtering.

[check if one date is between two dates (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates-javascript)

However, if you will need to do this range picking alot, then sorting it first and doing the faster binary search for the interval ends would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Easy! you have most of it actually
this will filter between a range of dates,
you just have to get "10 days ago" date and todays date and filter for anything between those dates.

```
//start date ten days ago
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 10);
//today
var endDate= new Date(); 

var filteredDates= JSON.parse(eventsObjects).filter(
   ({date}) => 
       date >= startDate && date <= endDate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parsed JSON string contained the dates as strings and these dates are still represented as strings in the resulting object you could do the filtering like this:

```js
const eventsObjects=[{a:123, date:'2019-10-02'},{a:1123, date:'2019-10-03'},{a:11123, date:'2019-10-09'},{a:111123, date:'2019-10-12'},{a:444123, date:'2019-10-13'},{a:44123, date:'2019-10-31'},{a:4123, date:'2019-11-09'},{a:5123, date:'2019-12-13'}];

var fmt=days=>{ 
 var dat=new Date((new Date()).getTime()+days*86400000);
 var dd = String(dat.getDate()).padStart(2, '0'),
     mm = String(dat.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'),
   yyyy = dat.getFullYear();
 return yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
}
var d1=fmt(-10), d2=fmt(10); 
var eventParsed = eventsObjects.filter(({date}) =>
 (date>=d1 && date<=d2) );


console.log(eventParsed);
```

In this approach I generate the date strings *only once* from the current date object (adding and subtracting 10 days). The filtering itself then happens by comparing simple (date-)strings.