# How to filter out array within array of objects based on date range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have an array of objects, each element looking something like this:

```
campaigns: (5) ["get.dentalintel.net/call-insight-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/practice-analysis-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/morning-huddle-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/new-morning-huddle-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/followups-DeshaunWatson"]
email: "dwats@gmail.com"
name: "Deshaun Watson"
submissions: [{…}]
user_id: 166
```

within each element there is an array of submission objects that appear like this:

```
campaigns: (5) ["get.dentalintel.net/call-insight-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/practice-analysis-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/morning-huddle-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/new-morning-huddle-DeshaunWatson", "get.dentalintel.net/followups-DeshaunWatson"]
email: "dwats@gmail.com"
name: "Deshaun Watson"
submissions: Array(1)
0:
addedAt: 1574185321138
canonical-vid: 13476551
form-submissions: []
identity-profiles: [{…}]
is-contact: true
merge-audits: []
merged-vids: []
portal-id: 2271480
profile-token: "AO_T-mOo4xVvqmFyVkiizX8l0pCPZTakJOfo02uTm2kWzr68fzpXI6-xmyh4Gmj_Pzpp8IBDdbEN9CCRW4GeMfybZaSBiMZ8xXo2U2dylZ7QD3CufR-ERrazbZlKPaDyVzxaCqwvXU3W"
profile-url: "https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/2271480/contact/13476551"
properties: {partner_email: {…}, utm_campaign: {…}, lastmodifieddate: {…}, partner_last_name: {…}, email: {…}}
vid: 13476551
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
user_id: 166
```

The only property of note on this is the addedAt value. 
I want to filter out submission objects based on a date range. This is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
  filterByDate = () => {
    const { partners, endDate, startDate } = this.state;
    partners.forEach(partner => {
      for (let i = 0; i < partner.submissions.length; i++) {
        if (
          moment(partner.submissions[i].addedAt).isBetween(startDate, endDate)
        ) {
          return partners;
        } else {
          return partner.submissions.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

It removes some of the submission objects, but never the correct ones. Any suggestions on a better approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering use `Array.filter`. This returns a new array with only the values that meet the `boolean` returned from the `callback`. For creating a new array from existing arrays use `Array.map` instead of `Array.forEach`. forEach loop only iterates over the values but `Array.map` returns a modified or new value for every element.

```
const filterByDate = () => {
    const { partners, endDate, startDate } = this.state;
    const filteredPartners = partners.map(partner => {
        return {
            ...partner,
            submissions: partner.submissions.filter(submission =>
                moment(submission.addedAt).isBetween(startDate, endDate)
            )
        };
    });
};
```

**Example Array.filter and Array.map (No mutation)**

```js
const testArray = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 4
}]
const filtered = testArray.filter(e => e.id !== 3)
const mapped = testArray.map(e => {
  return {
    id: e.id,
    name: `Name of ${e.id}`
  }
})

console.log("Test Array: ", testArray)
console.log("Filtered Array: ", filtered)
console.log("Mapped Array: ", mapped)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much for the explanation. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` for this use case

```js
filterByDate = () => {
  const { partners, endDate, startDate } = this.state;
  partners.forEach(partner => {
    partner.submissions = partner.submissions.filter(sub =>  moment(partner.submissions[i].addedAt).isBetween(startDate, endDate));
  });
};
```