# How do i structure dates available of a "Place" model on a booking system? (mongoose and mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I`m designing a booking system(a place reservation system) and i`m having trouble designing my "Place" Schema. I need to keep track of its availability. Basically i need to find if a certain time frame chose by the user is still available or not. For example the user choses april-may as time of booking. How do i structure it in a way that i can find out if april-may is already taken.

Here`s what i did so far:
On my "Place" schema. i added an availability field:

```
availability: [
        {
            moveIn: { type: Date },
            moveOut: { type: Date },
            qty: { type: Number }
        }
    ]
```

i added quantity to find out how many persons booked on that certain time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic would be reserved for a few javascript and mongoose commands, its really up to you but I would recommend something like the following:

Your schema is fine, when a user goes to check out a book, you should first check if it's available.

You can do this by retrieving and unwinding the current dates into their own arrays. This also sorts the dates in order.

```
var datesIn = {};
Book.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$availability'},
    {$sort: {'availability.moveIn': 1}}
], function (err, result) {
    datesIn = result;
});
```

Do this again for dates out:

```
var datesOut = {};
Book.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$availability'},
    {$sort: {'availability.moveOut': 1}}
], function (err, result) {
    datesIn = result;
});
```

The index of each of these arrays now correspond to a checkout out time by a user. If empty, it's available, otherwise, you can use a library like moment.js to compare availability between dates.

Here is a good post about this: [Check if one date is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates)

Finally, once you have found availability, you can push in the new checkout like:

```
Books.findOneAndUpdate({'Searching criteria goes here'}, {
 $push : {
    availability :  {
             "moveIn": firstDate,
             "moveOut": secondDate, 
             "qty": quantityVal
           }  
  }
});
```

This should append to the `availability` array in your document.

### NOTE

Im sure you've heard of not re-inventing the wheel, there are some good libraries out there for things like this, here's one I found:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/availability-schedule

it seems to have an `isAvailable (startDate, endDate)` function. :)

Comment: no problem, I understand this is a lengthy task but please accept the answer if it helps down the line :)