# Make a value true if the start date is within a week from today and false after the end date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, logic

I want to display a picture in angular. There is a start date and end date. Pic should be up by start date and down by end date.

Basically, if today is the start date the pic should be up till the end date.

I have all the pieces but I can't fit them together

```
const startDate = new Date('02/28/2021');
const endDate = new Date('02/29/2021');
let todaysDate = new Date();
```

to get the numeric values of the date you can either use

```
todaysDate.valueOf();
```

or

```
todaysDate.getTime()
```

No need to worry about the html or other part of the code. Just a boolean would do.

Something like

```
if(condition)
    return true; // which would mean display the pic
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if one date is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be something like this:

```
return (Math.abs(endDate - startDate) < 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 week in milliseconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, I figured it out after talking out loud.

Answer (score 0):

```
      const startDate = new Date('02/27/2021').getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      const endDate = new Date('02/30/2021').getTime();
      const todaysDate = new Date().getTime();

      if(todaysDate >= startDate && todaysDate <= endDate){
        
      } else {
        
      }
```