# Issue highlighting node in d3 network with jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am stuck in a kind of thinking barrier. The graph contains 3 nodes, each of them got 2 date properties. I want to compare those date properties with a jQueryUI datepicker. The datepicker is a input field and works like expected.

At first I tried to do it with a for loop, which simply compare those dates. *This option works to 50%* as only the first node date will be considered. Further I thought about a forEach loop but this runs into an `Missing number at position 0` error. I am a bit confused, since I do not understand why forEach is throwing such an error. What do I miss?

Example: choose `20.09.2021` and one of the nodes get red. It should work for `25.09.2021` too but it doesn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/tj170smx/

```js
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": [{ "date": "10.09.2021" },
      { "date": "15.09.2021" }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "20.09.2021" },
      { "date": "25.09.2021" }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "07.10.2021" },
      { "date": "12.10.2021" }
    ]
  }],
  "links": [
    { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 3, "target": 1 }
  ]
}

// declare initial variables
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = 500;
var height = 500;

// define cavnas area to draw everything
svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

// remove zoom on dblclick listener
d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

// iniital force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }).distance(125))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-475))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(100))

//###############################################
//############### Initialization ################
//###############################################

initialize()

function initialize() {
  link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("class", "link")

  node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "node")

  node.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", "whitesmoke")

  node.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("text")
    .style("class", "icon")
    .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "-1em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[0].date
    })
  node.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "0.5em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[1].date //How to display these below each other, instead of next to each other?
    })

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(graph.links)
}


function ticked() {
  // update link positions
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  // update node positions
  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });

}

//###############################################
//################# Drag Nodes ##################
//###############################################

var minDate, maxDate;

$("#from").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate)

    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")

    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)

    var isMatching = []

    minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd.mm.yy", selectedDate)

    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
      /*
      fnodes.dates.forEach(date => {
          console.log(date) //list dates as string
          parseDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd.mm.yy", date) //parse date(string) to date(date)
          console.log(parseDate) //throws error [Uncaught Missing number at position 0]
          
      })
      */

      for (var i = 0; i < fnodes.dates.length; i++) {
        console.log(fnodes.dates[i].date)
        return fnodes.dates[i].date === selectedDate
      }

    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})

$("#to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")

    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)

    maxDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd.mm.yy", selectedDate)

    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {

    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e6e7ee;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
}

#dates {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.highlight {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Access Control Allow Origin" content="*">

  <title>datesInRange</title>
  <!-- d3.js framework -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Import-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- datepicker stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- jQuery UI Import -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg"> </svg>

  <div id="dates">
    <label class="label" id="label-range">SetRange</label>
    <input id="from" placeholder="from">
    <input id="to" placeholder="to">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include an [mcve] in your question itself, instead of just linking to an external snippet.

Comment: Post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Well, its the snipped I created for the question. I attached this directly with in practical example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on the start or end date defined for a node in your `graph` then you can use this:

```
filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
  return (fnodes.dates[0].date === selectedDate || fnodes.dates[1].date === selectedDate);
}).classed("highlight", true)
```

This is shown in the example below:

```js
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": [{ "date": "10.09.2021" },
      { "date": "15.09.2021" }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "20.09.2021" },
      { "date": "25.09.2021" }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "07.10.2021" },
      { "date": "12.10.2021" }
    ]
  }],
  "links": [
    { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 3, "target": 1 }
  ]
}

// declare initial variables
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = 400;
var height = 150;

// define cavnas area to draw everything
svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

// remove zoom on dblclick listener
d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

// iniital force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }).distance(20))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-475))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(50))

//###############################################
//############### Initialization ################
//###############################################

initialize()

function initialize() {
  link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("class", "link")

  node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "node")

  node.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", "whitesmoke")

  node.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("text")
    .style("class", "icon")
    .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "-1em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[0].date
    })
  node.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "0.5em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[1].date //How to display these below each other, instead of next to each other?
    })

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(graph.links)
}


function ticked() {
  // update link positions
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  // update node positions
  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });

}

//###############################################
//################# Drag Nodes ##################
//###############################################

var minDate, maxDate;

$("#from").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate)

    // clear node highlight
    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")
    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)
    
    // highlight any node with a date in it that matches selectedDate
    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
      return (fnodes.dates[0].date === selectedDate || fnodes.dates[1].date === selectedDate);
    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})

$("#to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    // todo
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e6e7ee;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
}

#dates {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.highlight {
  fill: red !important;
}

/* remove this - just to fit into the stackoverflow snippet */
.ui-datepicker { 
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Access Control Allow Origin" content="*">

  <title>datesInRange</title>
  <!-- d3.js framework -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Import-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- datepicker stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- jQuery UI Import -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg"> </svg>

  <div id="dates">
    <label class="label" id="label-range">SetRange</label>
    <input id="from" placeholder="from">
    <input id="to" placeholder="to">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Additionally, if you want to highlight a node when a date is selected between, and including, those dates then you can use this (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates)):

```
filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
  var d1 = fnodes.dates[0].date.split(".");
  var d2 = fnodes.dates[1].date.split(".");
  var sd = selectedDate.split(".");
  // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
  var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  
  var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
  var check = new Date(sd[2], parseInt(sd[1])-1, sd[0]);

  return (check >= from && check <= to);
}).classed("highlight", true)
```

This is shown in the example below:

```js
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": [{ "date": "10.09.2021" },
      { "date": "15.09.2021" }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "20.09.2021" },
      { "date": "25.09.2021" }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "07.10.2021" },
      { "date": "12.10.2021" }
    ]
  }],
  "links": [
    { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 3, "target": 1 }
  ]
}

// declare initial variables
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = 400;
var height = 150;

// define cavnas area to draw everything
svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

// remove zoom on dblclick listener
d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

// iniital force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }).distance(20))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-475))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(50))

//###############################################
//############### Initialization ################
//###############################################

initialize()

function initialize() {
  link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("class", "link")

  node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "node")

  node.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", "whitesmoke")

  node.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("text")
    .style("class", "icon")
    .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "-1em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[0].date
    })
  node.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "0.5em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[1].date //How to display these below each other, instead of next to each other?
    })

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(graph.links)
}


function ticked() {
  // update link positions
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  // update node positions
  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });

}

//###############################################
//################# Drag Nodes ##################
//###############################################

var minDate, maxDate;

$("#from").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate)

    // clear node highlights
    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")
    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)

    // filter nodes by the selectedDate falling on/ between
    // the two dates in any node
    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
      var d1 = fnodes.dates[0].date.split(".");
      var d2 = fnodes.dates[1].date.split(".");
      var sd = selectedDate.split(".");
      // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
      var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  
      var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
      var check = new Date(sd[2], parseInt(sd[1])-1, sd[0]);
      // return the filter
      return (check >= from && check <= to);
    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})

$("#to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    // todo
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e6e7ee;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
}

#dates {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.highlight {
  fill: red !important;
}

/* remove this - just to fit into the stackoverflow snippet */
.ui-datepicker { 
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Access Control Allow Origin" content="*">

  <title>datesInRange</title>
  <!-- d3.js framework -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Import-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- datepicker stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- jQuery UI Import -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg"> </svg>

  <div id="dates">
    <label class="label" id="label-range">SetRange</label>
    <input id="from" placeholder="from">
    <input id="to" placeholder="to">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

A third example is if you want to use both the *from* and *to* datepickers to define a range and then highlight any node where the range in the picker falls on/ within the range in a node.

In this case you move all the logic to the event logic in the *to* node:

```
$("#to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    // min date from 'from' picker
    // max date is selectedDate from 'to' picker
    var minDate = $("#from").val();

    // the nodes in the graph
    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")

    // clear node highlight
    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)
    
    // filter for nodes to highlight
    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
      var d1 = fnodes.dates[0].date.split(".");
      var d2 = fnodes.dates[1].date.split(".");
      var sd1 = minDate.split(".");
      var sd2 = selectedDate.split(".");
      // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
      var nodeFrom = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  
      var nodeTo = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
      var pickerFrom = new Date(sd1[2], parseInt(sd1[1])-1, sd1[0]);
      var pickerTo = new Date(sd2[2], parseInt(sd2[1])-1, sd2[0]);

      // comparison on of dates in node vs to and from
      return (pickerFrom >= nodeFrom && pickerTo <= nodeTo);
      
    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})
```

Shown in this example:

```js
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 1,
    "dates": [{ "date": "10.09.2021" },
      { "date": "15.09.2021" }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "20.09.2021" },
      { "date": "25.09.2021" }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "dates": [
      { "date": "07.10.2021" },
      { "date": "12.10.2021" }
    ]
  }],
  "links": [
    { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
    { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
    { "source": 3, "target": 1 }
  ]
}

// declare initial variables
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var width = 400;
var height = 150;

// define cavnas area to draw everything
svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("class", "canvas")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

// remove zoom on dblclick listener
d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

var linksContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "linksContainer")
var nodesContainer = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodesContainer")

// iniital force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  }).distance(20))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-475))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collision", d3.forceCollide().radius(50))

//###############################################
//############### Initialization ################
//###############################################

initialize()

function initialize() {
  link = linksContainer.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .join("line")
    .attr("class", "link")

  node = nodesContainer.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "node")

  node.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 30)
    .style("fill", "whitesmoke")

  node.selectAll("text")
    .data(d => [d])
    .join("text")
    .style("class", "icon")
    .attr("font-family", "FontAwesome")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "-1em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[0].date
    })
  node.append("text")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", 13)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("dy", "0.5em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.dates[1].date //How to display these below each other, instead of next to each other?
    })

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(graph.links)
}


function ticked() {
  // update link positions
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  // update node positions
  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });

}

//###############################################
//################# Drag Nodes ##################
//###############################################

var minDate, maxDate;

$("#from").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    // set min date on 'to' datepicker
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    // ... then let 'to' picker handle the highlighting logic
  }
})

$("#to").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {
    // min date from 'from' picker
    // max date is selectedDate from 'to' picker
    var minDate = $("#from").val();

    // the nodes in the graph
    const filNodes = node.selectAll("circle")

    // clear node highlight
    filNodes.classed("highlight", false)
    
    // filter for nodes to highlight
    filNodes.filter((fnodes) => {
      var d1 = fnodes.dates[0].date.split(".");
      var d2 = fnodes.dates[1].date.split(".");
      var sd1 = minDate.split(".");
      var sd2 = selectedDate.split(".");
      // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
      var nodeFrom = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  
      var nodeTo = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
      var pickerFrom = new Date(sd1[2], parseInt(sd1[1])-1, sd1[0]);
      var pickerTo = new Date(sd2[2], parseInt(sd2[1])-1, sd2[0]);

      // comparison on of dates in node vs to and from
      return (pickerFrom >= nodeFrom && pickerTo <= nodeTo);
      
    }).classed("highlight", true)
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e6e7ee;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
}

#dates {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.highlight {
  fill: red !important;
}

/* remove this - just to fit into the stackoverflow snippet */
.ui-datepicker { 
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -180px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="Access Control Allow Origin" content="*">

  <title>datesInRange</title>
  <!-- d3.js framework -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Import-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- datepicker stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <!-- jQuery UI Import -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="svg"> </svg>

  <div id="dates">
    <label class="label" id="label-range">SetRange</label>
    <input id="from" placeholder="from">
    <input id="to" placeholder="to">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks once again Robin, you already helped me out like 100 times! To highlight each node in a certain range was my next step which you already thought about to, insane. I guess you mixed up, during copy paste, as the range function isn´t working. Once more, you are really a star for the D3 community. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @ICoded - thanks :) I updated the answer to provide a third example of moving the highlight logic to the 'to' picker such that picking a date in 'from' and a date in 'to' will highlight nodes where the dates in the pickers fall on/ between the dates in the nodes. HTH