# How we can check if Current date is between(in range) from date and to date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Note: date is in (dd/mm/yyyy) format and this is what, I need to use and
I have tried this

```
function dateCheck(from, to, currentdate) {

    var fDate, lDate, cDate;
    fDate = Date.parse(from);
    lDate = Date.parse(to);
    cDate = Date.parse(currentdate);

    if ((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

but in some cases, I don't get the expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if one date is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates)

Comment: "dd/mm/yyyy" is not a standard date format: [What are valid Date Time Strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715259)

Comment: If you format both dates as `yyyymmdd` you can compare them as strings and check if the given date is **>=** than `rangeStart` while at the same time **<=** than `rangeEnd`.

Comment: @VLAZ—re "*dd/mm/yyyy" is not a standard date format*". It is, globally, an extremely common format, just that most (all?) ECMAScript date parsers assume the peculiar US m/d/y format.

Comment: @RobG I'm not saying that's not a format that is used ever. I'm saying it is not valid as per the ECMAScript standard. Hence you get non-standard (implementation-dependent) behaviour. Because the spec doesn't say how these dates should be handled.

Comment: See [*Convert dd-mm-yyyy string to date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date)