# Apps Script Time Based Conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

My apologies if I don't word this perfectly as I am a novice coder. I am Using Googles Apps Script I am trying to setup a system to conditionally format cells within Google Sheets. This is for a system that will check admission dates of physicians from a .CSV and check the most recent MD or NP treatment date. For the first 90 days since admission a visit needs to occur in the 0-30 range, the 30-60 range, and the 60-90 range.

My problem is with writing code that will check whether the last MD treatment date is within a range of 30-60 days from the admission.

For the example code before I am attempting to look at a line item where a the admission date is between 40-50 days old. This would place it within the 30-60 range. I want to verify if the LastMDTreatment date is outside (admissiondate+30days , admissiondate+60days). **If there is no visit between 30-60 range on day 40-50 I would like to highlight the cell yellow.**

```js
function applyFilter(p, data) {
  //setting up the admission days by pulling from the .csv and then calculating how many days since 
  let dateAdmissionDate = new Date(p.admissionDate);
  console.log('dateAdmissionDate:', dateAdmissionDate);
  let today = new Date();
  let AdmissionDays = Math.floor((today.getTime() - dateAdmissionDate.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  //setting up the MDtreatmentdays and NP treatment days by pulling the last treatment dates from the .csv and then seeing how many days from today its been
  let dateLastMDTreatmentDate = new Date(p.lastMDTreatmentDate);
  let dateLastNPTreatmentDate = new Date(p.lastNPTreatmentDate ? p.lastNPTreatmentDate : p.admissionDate);
  var MDTreatmentDays = Math.floor((today.getTime() - dateLastMDTreatmentDate.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var NPTreatmentDays = Math.floor((today.getTime() - dateLastNPTreatmentDate.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  //if its past admission day 40 and before day 50 and there is a there is only an MD treatment day in the admission days 0-30 then its time to warn the MD cell so the MD will know to start a visit

  if (AdmissionDays >= 40 && AdmissionDays <= 50 && MDTreatmentDays >= 10 && MDTreatmentDays <= 20) {
    console.log('filter rule 4 activated');
    out.colors[p.lastMDTreatmentDateCol] = color_warn;
    out.notes[p.lastMDTreatmentDateCol] = 'A visit needs to occur every 30 days for the initial 90 days. Admission ' + AdmissionDays + ' days ago. It has been ' + MDTreatmentDays + ' days since the last MD visit';
    out.skip = false;
  }
```

My issue with the code as it stands is if its admission day 45 and a MD visit occurred 11 days ago on day 34 this code would erroneously highlight it. Or if its admission day 40 and there was a MD visit 10 days ago it would erroneously highlight it. I figure I need some sort of iterative way of going about this but again given my coding novice I cant figure out a solution. The code does run in its current aspect I'm just finding conditional formatting logic rules to be beyond my understanding.

For the example assume todays date is December 1st, 2023.

To allow better understanding of how this would work here is the csv that will be parsed by the tool would look. To be clear all information in this is fictitious.

| Last | First | Admit | Admission Days | MD | MD Treatment | MD Visit Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pulliam | Brooklynn | 10/17/2023 | 45 | Deborah Anne | 11/20/2023 | 11 |
| Way | Sofia | 11/7/2023 | 24 | John Smith | 11/12/2023 | 19 |
| Brothers | Dayna | 10/21/2023 | 41 | John Smith | 11/8/2023 | 23 |
| Bailey | Emani | 10/26/2023 | 36 | Dave Ramsey | 11/3/2023 | 28 |
| McGinnis | Brielle | 10/21/2023 | 41 | Mark Wahlberg | 11/17/2023 | 14 |
| Everett | Jaya | 10/21/2023 | 41 | John Smith | 11/24/2023 | 7 |
| Knox | Joaquin | 10/29/2023 | 33 | John Smith | 11/30/2023 | 1 |
| Melvin | Eli | 10/20/2023 | 42 | Mark Wahlberg | 11/27/2023 | 4 |

And ideally the output would be formatted and look like this. Yellow is the cells that would be highlighted yellow by properly working code .

| Last | First | Admit | Admission Days | MD | MD Treatment | MD Visit Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pulliam | Brooklynn | 10/17/2023 | 45 | Deborah Anne | 11/20/2023 | 11 |
| Way | Sofia | 11/7/2023 | 24 | John Smith | 11/12/2023 | 19 |
| Brothers | Dayna | 10/21/2023 | 41 | John Smith | 11/8/2023 **yellow** | 23 |
| Bailey | Emani | 10/26/2023 | 36 | Dave Ramsey | 11/3/2023 | 28 |
| McGinnis | Brielle | 10/21/2023 | 41 | Mark Wahlberg | 11/17/2023 **yellow** | 14 |
| Everett | Jaya | 10/21/2023 | 41 | John Smith | 11/24/2023 | 7 |
| Knox | Joaquin | 10/29/2023 | 33 | John Smith | 11/30/2023 | 1 |
| Melvin | Eli | 10/20/2023 | 42 | Mark Wahlberg | 11/27/2023 | 4 |

But I believe my code as currently written would be too "dumb" to catch this. As on admission day 45 with a MD visit 11 days ago it would highlight the cell.

To have it as simple as possible this is the list of conditions I want to have highlighted.

| Admission Day | MD Visit Day |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | greater than 10 and less than 40 |
| 41 | greater than 11 and less than 41 |
| 42 | greater than 12 and less than 42 |
| 43 | greater than 13 and less than 43 |
| 44 | greater than 14 and less than 44 |
| 45 | greater than 15 and less than 45 |
| 46 | greater than 16 and less than 46 |
| 47 | greater than 17 and less than 47 |
| 48 | greater than 18 and less than 48 |
| 49 | greater than 19 and less than 49 |
| 50 | greater than 20 and less than 50 |

Where given the admission day it changes the range I should be using for MD Visit Days. Do we think I should rewrite this following line of code

```js
if (AdmissionDays >= 40 && AdmissionDays <= 50 && MDTreatmentDays >= 10 && MDTreatmentDays <= 20) {
```

To look like this following code

```js
if (AdmissionDays >= 40 && AdmissionDays <= 50 && MDTreatmentDays > (AdmissionDays - 30) && MDTreatmentDays <
  AdmissionDays) {
```

It feels like I should be setting a date range as admission date until admission date + 30 days and if the MD treatment Date is within that range highlight the cell.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect of your function `applyFilter`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You are asking a question that I might expect to hear between my dentist and his office manager.  Unfortunately, I doubt that most of the volunteers here are either doctors or office managers. We are programmers.  So can you ask us a programming question?

Comment: `if its past admission day 40 and before day 50 and there is a there is only an MD treatment day in the admission days 0-30 then its time to warn the MD cell so the MD will know to start a visit` This is from the script but it is not mentioned in the body of the question. OTOH, the script doesn't seem to place any focus on the specific ranges that _are_ mentioned in the question  (0-30,30-60,60-90). May I respectfully suggest that you edit the question to describe exactly what this script is designed to do, and include relevant sample values and expected results (as requested by @Tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike I have tried to update the description to be more relevant and included relevant sample values and desired results. If you need more clarification let me know, it can be hard for me as an amateur to know what other need to help me properly

Comment: @Cooper I wanted to provide greater context to what the problem I'm attempting to solve is. Because I am unsure if the way I am looking at the problem is the issue and my solution is not salvageable.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have attempted to append the description to explain what is going on with my script. The 30-60 range is when the treatment date needed to occur. The 40-50 date is just an arbitrary timeline I decided would be helpful to start to notify people.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your added 2 images. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect of your function applyFilter? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: 1. For example, 5 rows of patient names, dates(just the needed columns-don't include all columns) and the expected output -i.e., which of those rows should be highlighted and why. 2. It's unclear, why this is erroneous: `its admission day 45 and a MD visit occurred 11 days ago on day 34 this code would erroneously highlight it.`

Comment: @TheMaster Here is an amended set of example information and desired outcome

Comment: @Tanaike The script I am showing is designed to determine when a Admit date is between 40-50 days old and the most recent MD Treatment Date is from before the 30th admission day.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Table is better. However, it is still hard to understand your problem. [Edit] to explain in plain English, why those two rows should be highlighted yellow with the exact math and also explain why one of those rows shouldn't be highlighted yellow. For eg, *Dayna Brothers admission date is 11/30/21 and MD date is 7/7/21 and today is 8/7/21. The difference  between admission date and MD date is 50, which is within 30-60 range.... therefore...*

Comment: @TheMaster I have added a table that shows which specific lines would fall within the rules to be highlighted.

Comment: @Tanaike No apologies needed. I greatly appreciate your effort. Take a look at my suggested rewrite of code and my table that shows under what instance I would like to have my code start.

Comment: Seems like `if (AdmissionDays >= 40 && AdmissionDays <= 50 && MDTreatmentDays > (AdmissionDays - 30) && MDTreatmentDays <
  AdmissionDays) {` works. Do you still need help?

Comment: @TheMaster I believe so. Is there a way to mark this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve the specific issue of how to determine whether a date occurred within a set range of time after a prior date. For alternative solutions to this coding problem click this link to the Stack Overflow forum post here: [Check if one date is between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates).

```js
if (AdmissionDays >= 40 && AdmissionDays <= 50 && MDTreatmentDays > (AdmissionDays - 30) && MDTreatmentDays <
  AdmissionDays) {
```